# mongodb $elemMatch

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

According to mongodb doc, syntax for $elemMatch would be,

```
t.find( { x : { $elemMatch : { a : 1, b : { $gt : 1 } } } } )
```

I have tried and it works fine.
The above means that, it can find if an object {a:1, b:'more than 1'} exist in the array x.

I have a requirement, where I need to figure out, if all the objects in an array exist in the database or not.

for example, let's say I have an array,

```
a=[{a:1, b:2},{a:3, b:4}, {a:5, b:6}]
```

and I need to find out if x contains all of them.

t.find( { x : { $elemMatch : { a : {$all:[1]}, b : {$all:[2]} } } } ) and it finds out all x containing {a:1, b:2}

But if I try, `t.find( { x : { $elemMatch : { a : {$all:[1,3]}, b : {$all:[2,4]} } } } )`, it fails. I know this is not correct. 
Is there any way I can achieve this ?
Ideallt, it should be,

```
t.find( { x : { $elemMatch : {$all:[ {a:1, b:2}, {a:3, b:4}] } } )
```

I tried, it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
t.find({$and:[{a:{$elemMatch:{a:1, b:2}}}, {a:{$elemMatch:{a:3, b:4}}}, {a:{$elemMatch:{a:5, b:6}}}]})
```

It isn't a particularly high performance option though.

Comment: this seems to solve my problem, even though I have a third element 'c' present. Thanks much !

Comment: Cool. Be sure to run explain()s on your query to see what kind of performance an index hitting it does.

Comment: Thanks. Fortunately I have another implementation which does not need to invoke this query.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use **elemMatch** for this, but you can simply just create a query which checks whether *a* matches the whole array:

```
db.items.insert({ 'foo' : 1, 'a' :  [{a:1, b:2},{a:3, b:4}, {a:5, b:6}]});
db.items.insert({ 'foo' : 1, 'a' :  [{a:1, b:2},{a:3, b:4}, {a:8, b:7}]});
db.items.find({'a': [{a:1, b:2},{a:3, b:4}, {a:8, b:7}]});

{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f3391856e196eca5eaa7518"), "foo" : 1, "a" : [ { "a" : 1, "b" : 2 }, { "a" : 3, "b" : 4 }, { "a" : 8, "b" : 7 } ] }
```

However, for this to work the order of the elements in the array need to be the same for the document and the query. The following will not find anything:

```
db.items.find({'a': [{a:3, b:4},{a:1, b:2}, {a:8, b:7}]});
```

(Because **{a:3, b:4}** and **{a:1, b:2}** are swapped).

Comment: Thanks. this is good. my problem is, I have a 'c' also as in {a:1, b:2, c:'adsasdasdasd'} and I do not want to compare c. forgot to mention that in my last post.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
db.items.find({x : { $all: [
  {$elemMatch: {a: 1, b: 2}}, 
  {$elemMatch: {a: 3, b: 4}}, 
  {$elemMatch: {a: 5, b: 6}}
    ]}}
```

Check out the Mongo [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/#use-all-with-elemmatch).

Also, note the docs warning:

> In the current release, queries that use the $all operator must scan
>   all the documents that match the first element in the query array. As
>   a result, even with an index to support the query, the operation may
>   be long running, particularly when the first element in the array is
>   not very selective.